# How do I use Django subqueries?

Tags: python, django

How do I use this subquery in Django ORM?

```
select id, name, price from book 
where price > (select avg(price) from book);
```

I tried this and got an error.

```
Book.objects.filter(price__gt=Subquery(Book.objects.aggregate(Avg('price')))).values('id', 'name', 'price')
```

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'query'
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use annotate expression along with filter as,

```
from django.db import models

Book.objects \
    .annotate(avg_price=models.Avg('price')) \
    .filter(price__gt=models.F('avg_price'))
```